# Tutorial on faceted search with java and lucene 3.6

Tags: java, lucene, faceted-search

I'm looking for a tutorial about faceted search using java and lucene 3.6. I don't want to user solr. I need something that describe the steps needed to make the index (with categories, etc.) and how to do the search, classes and methods to use, etc. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I wrote a small tutorial on faceted search using java and lucene 4: http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/faceted-search-with-lucene/ The code is written for lucene 4.0 but it should work okay with lucene 3.6 with some minor modifications.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may help you.
It is official user guide.
 1. http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/contrib-facet/org/apache/lucene/facet/doc-files/userguide.html
 2. http://shaierera.blogspot.com/2012/11/lucene-facets-part-1.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a a tutorial for generating a quick Lucene search - http://www.hascode.com/2010/03/how-to-build-a-quick-lucene-search/

It might be a bit too basic for you though

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this page does not tell nothing about faceted indexing and searching...

Comment: Now there is a tutorial on faceting with Lucene solely on my blog: http://www.hascode.com/2012/08/lucene-snippets-faceting-search/

Answer (score 0):

But on the same blog there's a tutorial how to achieve faceting using Hibernate Search so there is Lucene and JPA under the hood but perhaps this is not a combination that you're searching for:

- http://www.hascode.com/2012/03/hibernate-search-faceting-discrete-and-range-faceting-by-example/

In the Lucene 4.x documentation there's a whole chapter about this topic but it is an early release:

- http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/facet/org/apache/lucene/facet/doc-files/userguide.html

If you've found a better source, please keep us up to date :)